# Django Admin: has_delete_permission Ignored for "Delete" Action

Tags: django, django-admin

Let's say that I have a model where the row that has an ID of 1 is special and should not be able to be deleted, but all the other rows are fine to delete. Here is my attempt at implementing that logic:

## models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Widget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Widget


class WidgetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return obj is None or obj.pk != 1

admin.site.register(Widget, WidgetAdmin)
```

The above code removes the "Delete" button from the change form when `obj.pk` is `1`, which is what I want. However, on the change list, if I check the checkbox for the row with an ID of 1 and then use the "Delete selected widgets" action, I am able to delete that row. I want to prevent that, but still allow all of the other rows to be deleted with the "Delete selected widgets" action. How can I do this?

Comment: I was going to reply to your comment to say that this was probably a performance optimization so that the action can use `queryset.delete()` instead of fetching each instance. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/64aba7a8aba06b8be52a1a099b44e1d3be4bdd26/django/contrib/admin/actions.py#L46), though, it turns out that the queryset is iterated over anyway! More investigation reveals that your exact concern has been an [accepted, but untouched, bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11383) for the last 7 years.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks for finding that bug! It's good to know that this is a known issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [`has_delete_permission`'s docstring](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L448-L461):

```
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    """
    Returns True if the given request has permission to change the given
    Django model instance, ...
    """
```

This means `has_delete_permission` is executed per request, not per object. On a bulk action, `obj` is not set. However you may examine `request`:

```
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if request.POST and request.POST.get('action') == 'delete_selected':
        return '1' not in request.POST.getlist('_selected_action')
    return obj is None or obj.pk != 1
```

Note that the above works because [the `delete_selected` action **takes `has_delete_permission` into account**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/contrib/admin/actions.py#L29).

You may also want to provide some details about the error:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if request.POST and request.POST.get('action') == 'delete_selected':
        if '1' in request.POST.getlist('_selected_action'):
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, (
                "Widget #1 is protected, please remove it from your selection "
                "and try again."
            ))
            return False
        return True
    return obj is None or obj.pk != 1
```

I guess `has_delete_permission` is called per request rather than per object for performance reasons. In the general case, it is useless to make a `SELECT` query and loop over `has_delete_permission` (which may be time consuming according to what it does) prior to running the `DELETE` query. And when it's relevant to do so, it's up to the developer to take the necessary steps.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks! As a side note, a simplified version of `messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Oh no!')` is `messages.error(request, 'Oh no!')`

Answer (score 8):

You can replace the admin's implementation of the `delete_selected` action with your own. Something like:

```
from django.contrib.admin import actions

class WidgetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [delete_selected]

    def delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        # Handle this however you like. You could raise PermissionDenied,
        # or just remove it, and / or use the messages framework...
        queryset = queryset.exclude(pk=1)

        actions.delete_selected(self, request, queryset)
    delete_selected.short_description = "Delete stuff"
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#writing-actions) for more details.