# Is it possible to prevent deleting multiple objects at once from leaving <2 objects remaining in the Django admin site?

Tags: python, django, post, django-admin

I have a Highlight class with a ForeignKey relationship to the Organism class. On the admin site, Highlights are an inline of Organism. I want each organism object to have 2-5 highlights. I want it to be impossible to use the Organism admin page to delete highlights from an organism in a way that leaves <2 remaining.

In models.py:

```
class Organism(BaseModel):
    ...

class Highlight(BaseModel):
    organism = models.ForeignKey(Organism, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class HighlightAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
```

In admin.py:

```
class HighlightInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Highlight
    max_num = 5
    extra = 1
    min_num = 2
    ...
    line_numbering = 0

    def count(self):
        return self.line_numbering

    def line_number(self, obj):
        self.line_numbering += 1
        return self.line_numbering

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, (
                    request.POST.dict(), request
                ))
        if obj.highlight_set.count() > self.min_num:
            return True
        elif obj.highlight_set.count() == self.min_num:
            return False
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, (
                    "Can't have fewer than 2 highlights"
                ))
        return False
        # return return super().has_delete_permission(request, obj)

class OrganismAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [HighlightInline]

...

admin.site.register(Organism, OrganismAdmin)
admin.site.register(Highlight, HighlightAdmin)
```

The function `has_delete_permission` counts the number of highlights associated with the organism we are deleting highlights from.
When there are 0-2 highlights, there are no Delete checkboxes (which is intended).
When there are >2 highlights, there are Delete checkboxes. If I have 3 highlights and delete one of them, the Delete boxes disappear and there are 2 remaining highlights (which is intended).
However, if I have 3 highlights and select 2-3 of them to delete at once, this leaves 0-1 remaining highlights (which is bad).

I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127581/django-admin-has-delete-permission-ignored-for-delete-action), and tried numbering the lines in the table for Highlights with the idea of using the data in the POST request to prevent deleting highlights #1 and #2. However, `request.POST.get('action') == 'delete_selected'` (from the thread) only works for deleting the highlights from the Highlight admin page, not from the Organism page with the highlights as inlines. Also, `has_delete_permission` seems to run once before deleting and twice after no matter how many highlights there are, and therefore displays the error message twice, and also doesn't prevent the actual deletion from happening.

One idea is to disable deletion from the organism page and make it possible to delete highlights only by finding the specific highlight in the Highlights page. Then make a field in Highlights instead of HighlightInline to number the highlights 1-5 and prevent deletion of highlights 1 and 2. However, I don't know how the renumbering of highlights would work once some are deleted. Also, this would require the user to search for the specific highlight they want to delete out of all existing highlights instead of easily deleting from the Organism page.

Is there a simple solution to this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.